# Using a factory as source data in angular-datatables doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, datatable

It's possible to use a factory as source data in angular-datatables?

Basically, I wish to return data in a variable and use it as source data.

**UPDATED (06/22/2016)**

Now this is my factory:

```js
statisticsModule.factory('globalFactory', function($rootScope, $http){

  var globalFactory = {};

  globalFactory.getUrl = function(){
    return $http.get('../statistics/php/config_statistics.json');
  };

  return globalFactory;

});
```

And this is my Controller

```js
statisticsModule.controller("dataController", dataController); //Fin controlador

  function dataController($scope, $http, globalFactory, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder){
    //Promise con el factory
    globalFactory.getUrl().then(function(response){

      //Obtener data
      var urlGlobal = response.data;
      //Filtrar data. arrayReportBD : Arreglo con las URL de los reportes
      var deserialize = angular.fromJson(urlGlobal.config.graph_conf_array.arrayReportBD);
      //Data Distribución de Estatus
      var urlStatus = deserialize[0];

      //Obtener data de Distribución de Estatus
      $http.get(urlStatus).success(function(data){

      console.log(data);

      var vm = this;
      vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(data)
      .withDOM('lfrtip')
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      .withLanguage({
        "sEmptyTable":     "No hay datos para cargar en la tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando _START_ de _END_ de _TOTAL_ entradas",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando 0 de 0 de 0 entradas",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtradas _MAX_ entradas totales)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ entradas",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron registros",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primera",
            "sLast":     "Última",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
          },
          "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": activar para ordenar de forma ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": activar para ordenar de forma descendente"
          }
        });
        vm.dtColumns = [
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('gob_code').withTitle('Cód. Gob.'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('fci_code').withTitle('Cód. FCI'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('NOMBRE'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('status').withTitle('ESTATUS')
        ];

      }).error(function(err){

      });//Fin $http

    });//Fin promise

  }//Fin función
```

**P.D.:**

1. I've datatables-scripts in correct position, indeed, if I use the data from a direct URL as source the view loads perfectly.
2. I've already added the ng-app in html tag
3. I want that the function to build datatables use data filtered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

****SOLVED 06/23/2015****

It was hard, but finally I could solve it!

1. **STEP ONE: CREATE MODULE:**

```js
var statisticsModule = angular.module("statisticsModule", ['datatables', 'datatables.bootstrap']);

//Bootstrap was added for best views
```

2. **STEP TWO: CREATE FACTORY**

```js
statisticsModule.factory('globalFactory', function($rootScope, $http){

  var globalFactory = {};

  globalFactory.getUrl = function(){
    return $http.get('../statistics/php/reports/r_reports_status.php').success(function(data){
      });
  };

  return globalFactory;

});

//Factory pointing to specific URL that contains the data
```

3. **STEP THREE: CREATE CONTROLLER**

```js
statisticsModule.controller("dataController", dataController);

  function dataController(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $scope, globalFactory){


      var vm = this;
      //Return data from factory
      vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function(){
        return globalFactory.getUrl().then(function(response){
          return response.data;
        })
      })
      .withDOM('lfrtip')
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      //Language Spanish (optional)
      .withLanguage({
        "sEmptyTable":     "No hay datos para cargar en la tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando _START_ de _END_ de _TOTAL_ entradas",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando 0 de 0 de 0 entradas",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtradas _MAX_ entradas totales)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ entradas",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron registros",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primera",
            "sLast":     "Última",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
          },
          "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": activar para ordenar de forma ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": activar para ordenar de forma descendente"
          }
        })
        //More options for best views
        .withDisplayLength(1)
        .withOption('responsive', true)
        .withBootstrap();
    //BELOW GOES vm.dtColumns and } that ends the function
```

4. **AND FINALLY, STEP FOUR: PUT INTO VIEW**

```html
<!--THIS IS THE ORDER-->

<head>
  
  <!--JQUERY SCRIPT-->
  <!--JQUERY DATATABLES SCRIPT-->
  <!--ANGULAR SCRIPT-->
  <!--ANGULAR DATATABLE SCRIPT-->
  <!--ANGULAR DATATABLE CSS-->
  <!--DATATABLES BOOTSTRAP CSS-->
  <!--DATATABLES RESPONSIVE CSS-->
  <!--MODULE-->
  <!--CONTROLLER-->
  <!--FACTORY-->
  <!--ANGULAR DATATABLES BOOTSTRAP SCRIPT-->
  <!--BOOTSTRAP SCRIPT-->
  
</head>

<body>
  
  <div ng-controller="dataController as showCase">
    <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered"></table>
  </div>
  
  <!--DATATABLES RESPONSIVE SCRIPT-->
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be more like this.
**Factory**

```
statisticsModule.factory('globalFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var GetStatistics = function () {
        return $http.get('../statistics/php/config_statistics.json');
    };
    return {
        GetStatistics: GetStatistics
    }
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
statisticsModule.controller("tableController", ['globalFactory', '$http',
    function (globalFactory, $http) {
    //.success is obsolete.
    globalFactory.GetStatistics().then(function (response) {
         //success
         // Initialize DataTable here
    }, function (response) {
        //fail
        //alert(response.data);
    });
}]);
```

> 3. In my attempt, the console throws me an error: `[ng-areq] statusController not a function got undefined`

Don't understand why you are passing `statusController` as an argument while registering the controller. Remove that.

**Update**

You can also use service

```
statisticsModule.service('globalService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.GetStatistics = function () {
        return $http.get('../statistics/php/config_statistics.json');
    };
}]);
```

And call it in controller like

```
globalService.GetStatistics().then(function (response) {
  //success
  // Initialize DataTable here
}, function (response) {
  //fail
  //alert(response.data);
});
```

Comment: In the Controller I should code the datatable inside the globalFactory.GetStatistics.then? Forgive my ignorance

Comment: yes. in `globalFactory` you are creating a method called `GetStatistics` and returning it. So we use `globalFactory.GetStatistics`. you can also use service

Comment: Show me an error by console: `Error: globalFactory.GetStatistics.then is not a function`

Comment: type.updated code. `globalFactory.GetStatistics().then`